# calling a categories thumbnail

Tags: php-5.4, thumbnail

I am trying to figure out the script on how to call magento's category thumbnail image to a specific location in my script can anyone guide me in the right direction with this?

I thought it would have been as simple as:

> ```
>                        <?php if($menu_type == 'mega-menu') { ?> 
>                         <?php if($_subcategory->getThumbnail()) { ?>
>                            <div class="nav-add" style="padding-top:15px;overflow:visible;">
>                             <div class="push_item1">
>                              <div class="push_img">
>                                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>"><img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$_subcategory->getThumbnail()  ?>" alt="<?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>" /></a>
>                              </div> <!--push_img-->
>                             </div> <!--push_item1-->
>                            </div> <!--nav-add-->
>                         <?php } ?>
>                     <?php } ?>
> ```

Comment: try this  $_subcategory->_getResource()->getThumbnail()

Comment: i tweaked it a little but got the answer, however would you happen to know where i can set the size of the actual thumbnail for the categories specifically?